# (Stone-Goldbart Ex 6.7) Use Neumann Problem to Derive Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

In Ex 6.7 part (a) of Stone-Goldbart, we are required to use the Fredholm condition for the existence of solution for a Neumann-Poisson problem to derive the Helmholtz decomposition. Given
\begin{align*}
-\nabla^2 \varphi &= f \\
\hat{n}\cdot\nabla\varphi &= g
\end{align*}
and if
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} f d^nr + \int_{\partial \Omega} g ds = 0
\end{align*}
holds over $\Omega$, then $\varphi$ exists and it is unique. Show that any smooth vector field $\vec{u}$ can be decomposed into $\vec{u} = \vec{v} + \nabla \phi$ where $\phi$ is unique up to a constant, and $\vec{v} \cdot n = 0$ along $\partial \Omega$, $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ throughout $\Omega$. I am having some difficulties to sort out the logics. I tried to use Divergence Theorem to write down
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} -\nabla \cdot \vec{u} d^nr + \int_{\partial \Omega} \hat{n} \cdot \vec{u} ds = 0
\end{align*}
and subtract the Fredholm condition from it to obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} -\nabla \cdot (\vec{u} - \nabla\varphi) d^nr + \int_{\partial \Omega} \hat{n}\cdot(\vec{u} - \nabla \varphi) ds = 0
\end{align*}
I attempt to rewrite $\vec{u} - \nabla\varphi = \vec{v}$, hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} -\nabla \cdot \vec{v} d^nr + \int_{\partial \Omega} \hat{n} \cdot \vec{v} ds = 0
\end{align*}
Now I am unsure if I can claim that I can select at will $\vec{v} \cdot n = 0$ and $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$, and how the uniqueness of $\vec{v}$ (and hence $\varphi$ or $\phi$) can hold. Any help would be appreciated! (Much appreciated if parts (b) and (c) can be addressed as well!)

Note: I am aware of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449486/the-proof-of-the-helmholtz-decomposition-theorem-through-neumann-boundary-value?rq=1), but it is centered at the uniqueness of the Neumann problem itself. And I want to how this can translate to the decomposition by the approach suggested by the textbook.